# Call truncate function inside .each loop when populating select options?

Tags: function, select, truncate

I'm trying to dynamically populate a select and call a truncate function in the loop... like below. I want to send the option text down to the function, truncate it if it's longer than 20 chars and send it back before it gets added to the option and appended to the select.

```
$(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.option.length; i++) {
            var truncatedText = truncate();
            var text = response.option[i].name;
            truncate(text);
            $("select").append("<option>" + truncatedText.text + "</option>");
        }
});

function truncate(text) {
    var textLength = text.length;
    if (textLength > 20) {
        text = text.substr(0, 20) + '...';
    }
    return text;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After jsfiddling for a while I landed on a working solution. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/pcb0a3Lg/9/

```
var namesList = ['johnathan', 'tim', 'greggory', 'ashton', 'elizabeth'];

$(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var name = namesList[i];
        $('#names').append('<option>' + name + '</option>');
    }
    var selected_option = $('#names').find('option:selected').val();
    var truncated = truncate(selected_option);
    $('option:selected').text(truncated.new);

    $('#names').change(function(){
       var selected_option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
       var truncated = truncate(selected_option);
        $('option:selected').text(truncated.new);
    });

});

function truncate(selected_option) {
    var nameLength = selected_option.length
    if (nameLength > 4) {
        selected_option = selected_option.substr(0, 4) + '...';
    }
    return {new: selected_option}
}
```